Why is a factor of 24 used in this Central Limit Theorem Question?
I have a question from Example 12.3.1 from Marcel B. Finan book Lecture Notes in Actuarial Mathematics
Question:
Let $X_i$, $i = 1, 2, \dots, 48$ be independent random variables that are uniformly distributed on the interval $[-0.5, 0.5]$. Find the approximate probability $P(|X| \leq 0.05)$, where $X$ is the arithmetic average of the $X_i$s.
Solution is:
Since each $X_i$ is uniformly distributed on $[-0.5, 0.5]$, its mean is $\mu = 0$ and its variance is $\sigma^2 = \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} x^2 dx = \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{0.5^3}{3} - \frac{(-0.5)^3}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{12}$. By the Central Limit Theorem, $X$ has approximate distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2/n) = N(0, \frac{1}{24^2})$. Thus $24X$ is approximately standard normal, so
$P(|X| \leq 0.05) \approx P(24 \cdot (-0.05) \leq 24X \leq 24 \cdot 0.05) = P(-1.2 \leq Z \leq 1.2) = \Phi(1.2) - \Phi(-1.2) = 2\Phi(1.2) - 1 = 0.7698$
I am unsure of the step "Thus $24X$
is approximately standard normal" specifically why we are using the 24.
I get that by CLT
$P\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}\left((X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n)/n) - \mu\right) \leq a\right) \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^a e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \, dx$
$=P\left(24X) \leq (a\right)$
But shouldn't we then divide yielding a different $a$ value and proceed from there?
This may be a simple error I am making. Appreciate in advance.

Something is wrong with brackets in the end: $=P\left(24X) \leq a\right)$.

You mean $P[\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}-\mu)\leq a] \rightarrow Gaussian$. So in your expression at the end (the same one Aig mentions) you neglect to divide by $n$. Note that $X=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. I observe in this case that $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}=\frac{\sqrt{48}}{\sqrt{1/12}}=24$.

I like to define $G_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}((\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-\mu)$, so then the CLT says (for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$) that $P[G_n\leq a] \rightarrow P[G\leq a]$ were $G \sim N(0,1)$. That is, $G_n$ is approximately $N(0,1)$ in its distribution (when $n$ is large).  It is not clear if you still have a question. In your case $\mu=0$ and $G_n=24X$. Note that there is no "$a$ value" in your problem since the CLT holds for all real numbers $a$. It looks like they are calling my $G_n$ variable $Z$.

if $X \sim N(0, \frac1{24^2})$, then $24X\sim N(0, 24^2 \cdot \frac1{24^2})$.
Recall that $Var(aX)=a^2 Var(X)$, hence $Var(24X)=24^2\cdot Var(X)$.
Also scalar multiple of a normal distribution remains normal.

Just made sense. Since it is standard normal the variance must be 1. Thank you for clarifying this trivial step.
